# How to pass Location type ArrayList to MapsActivity from MainActivity in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, location

What I'm trying to do is pass a list of locations to maps activity and put marker on those locations. I've tried using in MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Parcelable {

ArrayList<Location> locs=new ArrayList<>();
...
locs.add(location);
...
Intent in = new Intent(context,MapsActivity.class);
in.putExtra("setlocations",locs);
startActivity(in);
...
 @Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeList(locs);

}
}
```

And then in MapsActivity's onCreate()

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        locs=(ArrayList<Location>)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("setlocations");
        addMarkeratLocation();
    }
```

The `addMarkeratLocation()` method uses `locs` list for adding markers using for loop

```
public void addMarkeratLocation(){
    BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.dott);
    LatLng addpoint=new LatLng(0.0,0.0);
    for(int i=0;i<locs.size();i++){
        addpoint = new LatLng(locs.get(i).getLatitude(), locs.get(i).getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(addpoint).icon(icon));
     }
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(addpoint));
}
```

My application crashes when the intent is fired. And the logcat shows
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference`
Why it is showing `null`? This is first time I'm using Parcelable interface.. Is there anything that I'm missing? Any input will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1: First Import Gson Library using Gradle Script

Add this line in your Gradle dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
}
```

Step 2: Convert List into JSON String and pass the JSON String from MainActivity to MapsActivity

```
        Location location1 = new Location("");
        location1.setLatitude(12.124);
        location1.setLongitude(77.124);
        Location location2 = new Location("");
        location2.setLatitude(12.765);
        location2.setLatitude(77.8965);

        List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
        locations.add(location1);
        locations.add(location2);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonString = gson.toJson(locations);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("KEY_LOCATIONS",jsonString);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Step 3: Get the JSON String from Bundle and convert it to List

```
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String jsonString = bundle.getString("KEY_LOCATIONS");

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type listOfLocationType = new TypeToken<List<Location>>() {}.getType();
        List<Location> locations = gson.fromJson(jsonString,listOfLocationType );
```

I hope this might help you!!

Comment: There are multiple import options for `Type` package.. which one shall I import?

Comment: import java.lang.reflect.Type;

Comment: App crashes giving error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference` on the line of adding marker, this is how I'm adding marker `mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(addpoint).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));`

Comment: The variables location1 and location2 are incomplete that may be the issue but I'm not sure. Try to pass complete location variable. But above method will sure let you pass List<Location> to other Activity

Comment: I'm adding locations to the list in `onLocationChanged` method

Comment: It worked sir! Just changed the method call statement line. Thankyou :)

Comment: Fine go ahead!!

Answer (score 5):

```
`Location` class is not a Parcalable class.
```

`Intent.putExtra()` function only accept primitive and Parcelable data type. So you can not pass `List<Location>` through intent. Instead you can use `Gson` library to serialise you arraylist of Location and pass it as Json string to `MapActivity` and In `MapActivity` deserialise Json string to array of Location.

Comment: can you provide any example of that..?

Comment: Sure I'll put details answer

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList locs=new ArrayList<>();
Location class should be implemented with Parcelable, you already implemented Parcelable but it is for activity that should be for Location class.

Please refer below link for more info related your query.

[Passing arraylist of custom object to another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618863/passing-arraylist-of-custom-object-to-another-activity)

Comment: That Location class is the android's inbuilt class... how can I implement that with Parcelable??

Comment: you need to create your own class and that class should have that location class
example:- create another class MyLocationClass so array will be ArrayList<MyLocationClass> and MyLocationClass should have implemented with Parcelable.