# getIntent and ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I have an `ArrayList` in a first activity `ArrayList<ListeJoueurs> la = new ArrayList<>();`, defined as follows.
I would like to put this `ArrayList` into another activity.
I didn’t find a simple solution with `getIntent()`
What can I do, thank you so much for your help.

```
    public class ListeJoueurs {
    String  Nom;
    String  Prenom;
    Long  Licence;
    String  Cat;
    String Select;
    String dteN;
    int imageClick;
    // Constructor
    public ListeJoueurs(String Nom, String Prenom, Long Licence, String Cat, String Select, String dteN, int imageClick)
    {
        this.Nom = Nom;
        this.Prenom = Prenom;
        this.Licence = Licence;
        this.Cat = Cat;
        this.Select = Select;
        this.dteN = dteN;
        this.imageClick = imageClick;
    }

    // Used to print student details in main()
    public String toString()
    {
        return  this.Nom  + " " + this.Prenom + " " + this.Licence + " " + this.Cat + " " + this.Select + " " + this.dteN  + " " + this.imageClick;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to pass ArrayList of Objects from one to another activity using Intent in android?](//stackoverflow.com/q/13601883)

Comment: The solution you're looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46168121/7954210

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library to transfer data between Activities. You can convert a list of data to JSON and pass it. These links Can help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19700319/12980812

https://medium.com/@theblackcat102/passing-object-between-activity-using-gson-7dfa11d74e06

Comment: I tried the solution with Json, now it’s ok. I find my ArrayList in the other activity. Thank you very much